# NSubstitute Mocking Expressions along with params

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, expression, nsubstitute

I have a following class called TestClass and has one function.

In TestClass

```
 public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
```

This is How I am trying to mock the method above using NSubstitute.

```
  _testClass.GetAll(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Animal, bool>>>()).Returns(new List<Animal>(){new Animal(), new Animal()});
```

it complies fine but the mocked method when called does not include the two Animal object in the collection because collection length is zero. I have a feeling since I am not mocking the params part  as well thats why this issue is happening. Any one know how to properly mock it?

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it.

Following is how you should do it.

```
  test.GetAll(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Animal, bool>>>(),Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Animal,object>>>())
            .Returns(new List<Animal>(){new Animal(), new Animal()});
```